# Java generic method difference between T and <T> in method declaration?

Tags: java, generics

I would like to ask you why when we are declaring a method that returns a T (generic) element from an array for example, we declare the method as:

```
public T firstElement(){};
```

and sometimes method declaration appears to be

```
public static <T> void addElements(T a , T b ){};
```